# How do you utilize np.linalg.pinv to return this matrix

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra

For matrix X,
If `np.linalg.pinv(X)` equates to

> (X^T X)^(-1)(X^T)

For Constant C, and Identity Matrix I,

How do you utilize np.linalg.pinv to return

> (X^T X + CI)^(-1)(X^T)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit more of a maths question, but who cares. What about

```
pinv(X + C*pinv(X).T)
```

Proof of correctness: It is easily verified that the expression given in the question is *a* pseudo inverse of `X + Cpinv(X)^T`. It therefore remains to demonstrate that it has the same nullspace as *the* pseudo inverse. Since both can be written as RX^T for some R this is clear. q.e.d.